# How I can call a method by a string in Swift? (On iOS)

Tags: ios, swift, reflection

I want to call a method inside my class using only a string.

I know this type of manipulation is's called Reflection, but I couldn’t have find anything on web. And if this is possible, how I can call a method with parameters? Thank you.

Comment: didn't get what exactly you are trying to achieve. Can you please elaborate more with some code?

Comment: Swift has pretty limited reflection capabilities on its own, but on Apple’s platforms, Swift can Interoperate with Objective C and its runtime, which implements a full SmallTalk-style message passing system. See [`NSObject.performSelector(_:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/objectivec/nsobjectprotocol/1418867-perform) for example. That said, it’s clunky to use reflection in a statically typed language because you have to cast things everywhere to make compile time assertions about the types of objects that you get at runtime. You also forgo any compiler type checking

Comment: If you *could* select a method with a string and call it, what would you use it for? What’s your actual underlying problem you’re trying to solve?

Comment: I want to take a string from json (json have name of class and method) and after reading json call his method. I need to do this when app is already working